# Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, tutorial

Power supplies are available in a wide range of voltage and current ratings.  If I have a device that has specific voltage and current ratings, how do those relate to the power ratings I need to specify?  What if I don't know the device's specs, but am replacing a previous power supply with particular ratings?

Is it OK to go lower voltage, or should it always be higher?  What about current?  I don't want a 10 A supply to damage my 1 A device.

Comment: I think I've seen this question before ;) . All in favor of making this the canonical "consumer electronics power supply question" vote +1!

Comment: Not sure. I wonder if the wording might not be clear to the kind of person who needs to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Wording might need adjusting, but I agree with the idea - I think we could definitely do with a Community Wiki on choosing the right power supply.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question: What exactly do you think is poorly asked, unclear, ambiguous, etc?  We get questions closely related to this regularly, so the purpose was to write a detailed answer once that we can point to in the future.  This question and answer was essentially solicited in the meta post http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1268/4512

Comment: +1 for you ,  me too from here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/can-a-too-powerful-battery-damage-a-circuit

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/600401/2005

Answer (score 337, accepted):

### Voltage Rating

If a device says it needs a particular voltage, then you have to assume it needs that voltage.  Both lower and higher could be bad.

At best, with lower voltage the device will not operate correctly in a obvious way.  However, some devices might *appear* to operate correctly, then fail in unexpected ways under just the right circumstances.  When you violate required specs, you don't know what might happen.  Some devices can even be damaged by too low a voltage for extended periods of time.  If the device has a motor, for example, then the motor might not be able to develop enough torque to turn, so it just sits there getting hot.  Some devices might draw more current to compensate for the lower voltage, but the higher than intended current can damage something.  Most of the time, lower voltage will just make a device not work, but damage can't be ruled out unless you know something about the device.

Higher than specified voltage is definitely bad.  Electrical components all have voltages above which they fail.  Components rated for higher voltage generally cost more or have less desirable characteristics, so picking the right voltage tolerance for the components in the device probably got significant design attention.  Applying too much voltage violates the design assumptions.  Some level of too much voltage **will** damage something, but you don't know where that level is.  Take what a device says on its nameplate seriously and don't give it more voltage than that.

### Current Rating

Current is a bit different.  A constant-voltage supply doesn't determine the current: the load, which in this case is the device, does.  If Johnny wants to eat two apples, he's only going to eat two whether you put 2, 3, 5, or 20 apples on the table.  A device that wants 2 A of current works the same way.  It will draw 2 A whether the power supply can only provide the 2 A, or whether it *could* have supplied 3, 5, or 20 A.  The current rating of a supply is what it *can* deliver, not what it will always force thru the load somehow.  In that sense, unlike with voltage, the current rating of a power supply must be at least what the device wants but there is no harm in it being higher.  A 9 volt 5 amp supply is a superset of a 9 volt 2 amp supply, for example.

### Replacing Existing Supply

If you are replacing a previous power supply and don't know the device's requirements, then consider that power supply's rating to be the device's requirements.  For example, if a unlabeled device was powered from a 9 V and 1 A supply, you can replace it with a 9 V and 1 *or more* amp supply.

### Advanced Concepts

The above gives the basics of how to pick a power supply for some device.  In most cases that is all you need to know to go to a store or on line and buy a power supply.  If you're still a bit hazy on what exactly voltage and current are, it's probably better to quit now.  This section goes into more power supply details that generally don't matter at the consumer level, and it assumes some basic understanding of electronics.

- #### Regulated versus Unregulated

  #### Unregulated

  Very basic DC power supplies, called *unregulated*, just step down the input AC (generally the DC you want is at a much lower voltage than the wall power you plug the supply into), *rectify* it to produce DC, add a output cap to reduce ripple, and call it a day.  Years ago, many power supplies were like that.  They were little more than a transformer, four diodes making a full wave bridge (takes the absolute value of voltage electronically), and the filter cap.  In these kinds of supplies, the output voltage is dictated by the turns ratio of the transformer.  This is fixed, so instead of making a fixed output voltage their output is mostly proportional to the input AC voltage.  For example, such a "12 V" DC supply might make 12 V at 110 VAC in, but then would make over 13 V at 120 VAC in.

  Another issue with unregulated supplies is that the output voltage not only is a function of the input voltage, but will also fluctuate with how much current is being drawn from the supply.  A unregulated "12 volt 1 amp" supply is probably designed to provide the rated 12 V at full output current and the lowest valid AC input voltage, like 110 V.  It could be over 13 V at 110 V in at no load (0 amps out) alone, and then higher yet at higher input voltage.  Such a supply could easily put out 15 V, for example, under some conditions.  Devices that needed the "12 V" were designed to handle that, so that was fine.

  #### Regulated

  Modern power supplies don't work that way anymore.  Pretty much anything you can buy as consumer electronics will be a *regulated* power supply.  You can still get unregulated supplies from more specialized electronics suppliers aimed at manufacturers, professionals, or at least hobbyists that should know the difference.  For example, [Jameco](http://www.jameco.com) has wide selection of power supplies.  Their wall warts are specifically divided into regulated and unregulated types.  However, unless you go poking around where the average consumer shouldn't be, you won't likely run into unregulated supplies.  Try asking for a unregulated wall wart at a consumer store that sells other stuff too, and they probably won't even know what you're talking about.

  A regulated supply actively controls its output voltage.  These contain additional circuitry that can tweak the output voltage up and down.  This is done continuously to compensate for input voltage variations and variations in the current the load is drawing.  A regulated 1 amp 12 volt power supply, for example, is going to put out pretty close to 12 V over its full AC input voltage range and as long as you don't draw more than 1 A from it.

  #### Universal input

  Since there is circuitry in the supply to tolerate some input voltage fluctuations, it's not much harder to make the valid input voltage range wider and cover any valid wall power found anywhere in the world.  More and more supplies are being made like that, and are called *universal input*.  This generally means they can run from 90-240 V AC, and that can be 50 or 60 Hz.

  #### Minimum Load

  Some power supplies, generally older switchers, have a *minimum load* requirement.  This is usually 10% of full rated output current.  For example, a 12 volt 2 amp supply with a minimum load requirement of 10% isn't guaranteed to work right unless you load it with at least 200 mA.  This restriction is something you're only going to find in OEM models, meaning the supply is designed and sold to be embedded into someone else's equipment where the right kind of engineer will consider this issue carefully.  I won't go into this more since this isn't going to come up on a consumer power supply.

  #### Current Limit

  All supplies have some maximum current they can provide and still stick to the remaining specs.  For a "12 volt 1 amp" supply, that means all is fine as long as you don't try to draw more than the rated 1 A.

  There are various things a supply can do if you try to exceed the 1 A rating.  It could simply blow a fuse.  Specialty OEM supplies that are stripped down for cost could catch fire or vanish into a greasy cloud of black smoke.  However, nowadays, the most likely response is that the supply will drop its output voltage to whatever is necessary to not exceed the output current.  This is called *current limiting*.  Often the current limit is set a little higher than the rating to provide some margin.  The "12 V 1 A" supply might limit the current to 1.1 A, for example.

  A device that is trying to draw the excessive current probably won't function correctly, but everything should stay safe, not catch fire, and recover nicely once the excessive load is removed.

  #### Ripple

  No supply, even a regulated one, can keep its output voltage exactly at the rating.  Usually due to the way the supply works, there will be some frequency at which the output oscillates a little, or *ripples*.  With unregulated supplies, the ripple is a direct function of the input AC.  Basic transformer unregulated supplies fed from 60 Hz AC will generally ripple at 120 Hz, for example.  The ripple of unregulated supplies can be fairly large.  To abuse the 12 volt 1 amp example again, the ripple could easily be a volt or two at full load (1 A output current).  Regulated supplies are usually switchers and therefore ripple at the switching frequency.  A regulated 12 V 1 A switcher might ripple ±50 mV at 250 kHz, for example.  The maximum ripple might not be at maximum output current.

Comment: Personally, I think Johnny shouldn't be so wasteful with his apples..

Comment: +1! What about some tips on current limiting protection?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is old magnetic transformer plug packs have an optimal load range, otherwise the output voltage increases. And, some SMPS can have minimum load currents.

Comment: @clabacchio and others: Yes, there is a lot more that can be said about power supplies, like current limiting, low load issues, minimum load issues, regulation versus not, ripple, etc, etc.  This question is aimed at people that are worried their 10 A supply will kill their 2 A device, so let's keep it simple here.  Start another question with power supply nuances like those mentioned and more, and I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: :) I really appreciate this Q+A, probably you're right it's better to keep it simple, because this is the common issue

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think more details here like that being sectioned off is fair. I have no intent of CW'ing this post so you dont have to worry about precious reputation. Just use section headers to divide up the post so users can get what they need.

Comment: @Kortuk: OK, I'll add to it over time.  Right now I've got a customer breathing down my neck.  I'm only here now for a couple of minutes while doing a backup.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Ohh, no one understands only having so much time on the site more then I do, I bet you will get quite a few upvotes from it.

Comment: For readability I would make two headings, one reading 'Voltage' and one reading 'Current'. It helps navigating in the somewhat longish text.

Comment: @jippie: Yes, I will probably do some major edits this weekend. Right now I've got other stuff I have to do.

Comment: @variousResponders: I think that it is important to realize that people asking a question like this obviously don't know what current is, let alone current protection. Same goes for 'old magnetic' vs. 'SMPS' and 'ripple'. On several electronics sites I see enthousiasts like us overwhelming visitors with so much information and details, so much that they leave and probably never dare to return. I know all too well, it is a pitfall of my own too.

Comment: +1 awesome!,it solved me here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/can-a-too-powerful-battery-damage-a-circuit

Comment: As a complete noob here, I want to say that at least for me, 90% of the discussion is quite understandable, and extremely helpful. It would help me more if there were some community q/s's posted, with a note to Bulls in China shops such as myself, to look there before posting..

Comment: +1 Very detailed and helpful answer that is easy to understand!

Comment: It would be great to get some table for the presentation here about examples. Have different chargers and different phones, and list which combination is ok simply. Now, the answer covers very few combinations and cannot be easily expanded to cover more challenging systems. - - This answer receives much attention so I think answers should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Dell (LiteOn) laptop power supplies just stop supplying if overloaded. No current limiting.

Comment: This topic still confuses me a bit .. is there a  big difference between a battery source, a charger source and direct solar panel source?  if a device has a charge rating of 12v 1a and has built in overcharge protection built in, can you damage it by plugging in 12v 8a solar panel directly? If not, why do  devices like this have max watt charge rating?

Comment: @Olin the only thing missing in your answer is *what power source do I need if I  want to power several devices ?* Eg: "if I want to power 2 devices of 12V 1A on the same power supply, what power supply do I need?" (I guess 12V with at least 2 amps, right?)

Comment: Is it possible to use a wall adapter with a lower-rated current but higher power supply with the help of DCDC regulator?  For example, the wall adapter is 12v2A, the device is rated 3v4A, can I use the DCDC regulator to get the device reated current?

Comment: @OlinLathrop
Well, I have a power bank with 5V 2A input if connected to a USB port usually 5V 0.5-0.9A what is the effect of that a lower current from the USB and a higher current input required by the power bank?

Answer (score 53):

The three main parameters for a power supply are

- voltage
- type of voltage: AC or DC
- current

If your device or broken wall wart says 9 V DC, get a 9 V DC replacement. **The right voltage and type of voltage are important**: a too high voltage may damage your device, a too low voltage too, though that's less common. But at a too low voltage it may not work properly.

Get a power supply **at *minimum* the rated current**. If the device says 500 mA, get a power supply that can deliver *at least* that. A 100 mA wall wart may overheat and set your house on fire if not properly protected. A 1000 mA is safe, even if you only need 500 mA.

Olin explained with fruit, I'll try to explain with another flow: water. If my faucet can fill a bucket in a minute that's its maximum flow, or current. That's the 1000 mA the wall wart specifies. Yet I can open the faucet partly to fill my glass, and then I'm the 500 mA device. The faucet still *can* supply 10 liter per minute, but will supply less if I ask for less. I can ask for anything as long as it isn't more than the 10 liter per minute. If I want only a few drops to fill a thimble I'll be a 1 mA device. From a 1000 mA supply.

Comment: The transformer in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/transformer-labeled-120v-60hz-35va-12v-what-exactly-does-it-do says 12V(AC) and 35VA, it doesn't mention current at all. I know it isn't an adapter, but for the sake of this discussion what if it was?

Comment: @jippie, 35VA is 35 volt amps so to get the current divide by the voltage to get 35/12 amps or about 2.91 amps.

Comment: Does a 12V and 30A supply still seem safe if I only need 12V and 9 1A loads?

Comment: OK What if a power bank rated at 2A input connected to a USB port 0.5-0.9A output should this harm the power bank or the USB port?

Answer (score 22):

If you are replacing a "wall wart" with a salvaged one then there are a couple more things to be aware of in addition to what the other commenters have already said.

**AC/DC**: Power adapters can output either alternating current or direct current.  You must make sure it matches what the device expects.  Most adapters and devices are DC.  You can tell by looking at the symbols: a "~" symbol means AC, a "=" with a dashed line means DC.

**Polarity**: If you are using an adapter with the round barrel jacks, then be aware that sometimes the centre is positive and the outside is negative, and sometimes it is the opposite.  This must match what the device expects, or it could damage the device.  If it doesn't match then the fix is simple, just cut the jack off and swap the wires around.  There will be a symbol on the adapter showing which is positive and negative.  Usually it's "centre positive".

Comment: Regards USB adapters is it safe to assume they are always same polarity, right?

Comment: Yep, USB adapters always have the same polarity

Comment: +1 For mentioning **polarity**, which if incorrect can often kill a device. Nowadays polarity is mostly tip(center) positive, except on some devices that use the plug to switch between battery and AC power.

Answer (score 19):

A [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41903/psu-with-unspecified-max-safe-amperage) came up recently:

> I'd like to power my new LG M2450D monitor with a basicXL BXL-NBT-U02
>   universal AC-DC power adapter. This PSU is rated 90W max and supports
>   15-24V output voltage. The original monitor PSU (PA-1650-68) was fixed
>   at 19V and 3.32A.
>
> Now, doing the math: 90W / 19V = 4.74A
>
> Of course this is an ideal value, what is "safety margin" i should
>   assume for the real max amperage?

To be conservative in the face of ambiguous specifications like these, you should assume that the maximum power rating of the universal adapter occurs at the maximum output voltage, and that all lower output voltages are limited to the same current.

In this case, 90W/24V = 3.75A, so you should be good to go with the output set at 19V with this amount of current.

Comment: OK What if a power bank rated at 2A input connected to a USB port 0.5-0.9A output should this harm the power bank or the USB port?

Comment: @alsadk: No, it shouldn't. USB has protocols for negotiating power delivery among such devices. But that has nothing to do with what this question (and my answer) are about.

Comment: I am trying to use the same concept to figure out the effect on a power bank, my situation is using a USB port which is a part of DVB receiver used to connect HDDs to the receiver for the purpose of charging a power bank that needs a 5V 2A input, I am asking this because after doing this the power bank can be charging but it can not be used to charge devices. I just trying to know if the USB 0.5A current which is lower than the 2A required by the power bank could damage some circuitry.

Comment: @alsadk: This site is for questions about electronic design. Questions about the use of commercial devices are off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

> Power supplies are available in a wide range of voltage and current ratings. If I have a device that has specific voltage and current ratings ... is it OK to go lower voltage, or should it always be higher? What about current? I don't want a 10 A supply to damage my 1 A device.

See Olin's superb answer for a more detailed treatment.
My aim here is to directly address the two most common core question that many beginners come with. They are answered in Olin's response but (based on my significant experience assisting beginners) I consider they are well enough buried among other detail that they would be missed by many newcomers.

**Voltage:**

- **The specified voltage of device and the voltage of supply

  should always be close to identical.**
- What constitutes "close" varies with devices, but, as a guide
- A supply whose voltage is within -10% / +5% of device voltage rating will usually work and usually not cause damage. In a very few cases it may not work, but this would be unusual.
  For example, provided the current rating is adequate (see below)
- A 19V device will usually operate from an 18V supply.
- A 6V device may operate from a 5V supply - but as that's nearly 20% below spec, in some cases this difference may be too high
- A 16V device may well NOT operate from a 12V supply - in some cases it will.
  Damage to supply or device is unlikely but may occur.
  **BUT** trying to operate a 12V rated device from a 16V supply (25% high) is risky and may cause damage to device or supply.

**Current:**

- **A device that draws a specified current can be operated from a supply able to supply

  the same or higher current.**
- eg consider a 12V, 2A device and a 12V 20A power supply.
- 12V is the "electrical pressure".
  20A is the electrical current that the supply **CAN** provide at that pressure.
- 2A is the current that the load **WILL** take at that pressure.
  You then have 20-2 = 18A for use elsewhere.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to Olin's reply from 2012

Comment: @Cursorkeys I have been well aware of Olin's excellent answer for the last (almost) 7 years and cite it occasionally. What my answer adds is simplicity and direct addressing of the most common core question that many beginners come with. The answer is well addressed in Olin's effulgent tour de force - **BUT** requires some digging for by those overwhelmed with the subject. | A look at the many good comments by others will show that this point is well appreciated. eg see comment to Olin's answer "jippie Jun 29 '12 at 20:43" ...

Comment: ... worth repeating here: "@variousResponders: I think that it is important to realize that people asking a question like this obviously don't know what current is, let alone current protection. Same goes for 'old magnetic' vs. 'SMPS' and 'ripple'. On several electronics sites I see enthousiasts like us overwhelming visitors with so much information and details, so much that they leave and probably never dare to return. I know all too well, it is a pitfall of my own too. – jippie Jun 29 '12 at 20:43 "

Comment: I see where you are going, but I think we will have to agree to disagree. I think Olin's answer is already sufficient, as it has clear 'Voltage' and 'Current' sections and they are written quite succinctly. I'd worry specifically about someone with low knowledge reading your condensed version and misinterpreting the Voltage paragraph, as I don't feel it gets a basic level of detail across (how much is 'close', how would you judge that, why might it be bad, etc...).

Comment: @Cursorkeys I've answered "quite a few questions" and have a reasonable feel for how hard it is for newcomers to absorp [:-)]  information embedded in large amounts related but not wholly relevant detail. I wrote that answer in response to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/439618/3288) but it was closed before I got to click the answer button. The OP had been referred to Olin's answer - odds are he did not realise that you could click the link provided to get there. It may be blindingly obvious to you but I assure you it is nit so to many beginners. Really! So ...

Comment: @Cursorkeys ... I posted it as a comment on the OP's question and somewhat edited as an answer to Olin's question. I thought that if other related questions arose that were amenable to simple answers it may be worth adding module-lets to my answer over time. Maybe not. Have a look at what the OP said in response to my comment. I do not know if they have looked at Olin's answer or attempted to navigate it. Fine and well written as it is, it's not yet the ultimate eclectic source.

Comment: @Cursorkeys I've added "more words" while trying hard to maintain the essential simplicity of my original version. I thought the original was 'fit enough for purpose', but ... .

Comment: I like the changes you've made and I've moved my vote accordingly. I'm obviously not the judge and jury of what you post, and I hope you don't feel I was being pointlessly argumentative. I've handled my fair share of interns offline, and I like to think I too have at least some idea of how to handle beginner-level questions :)

Answer (score 5):

One thing that doesn't appear to be in the provided answers is about fusing and the possibility of a fire hazard. For instance, if you are using a supply that can deliver 1 amp **maximum** and you change it to a supply that can deliver (say) 10 amps **maximum** then for sure, it will still adequately power your "device" but, this might now become a fire hazard.

In the original set-up, your "device" may not have needed a fuse when working with the 1 amp (maximum) supply. If your device failed short-circuit, there would be little reason to suspect it might melt or burn when powered with the original 1 amp power supply under short-circuit conditions.

However, now that it's connected to (say) a 10 amp supply, if your device went short-circuit, it might very well become a fire hazard. To rectify this situation you would need to add a 1 amp fuse. I guess, for protection against fire, a replacement with anything more than the original rated current needs to be considered as a possible fire risk.