# If I make a power supply with the correct voltage, will the device automatically draw the correct current?

Tags: transformer, laptop

I lost my laptop power supply, and was wondering how it would be possible to make one. It needs 19.5V (Alternating current) and 3.9A so 75 Watts or so. My question is once the 110 or 230 V wall power is stepped down to the 19.5 volts, does there also have to be some kind of current limit inside the power supply device? Or is that just a bit of info regarding what the Laptop will normally use?

Comment: What laptop takes 19.5V AC? That's a very weird requirement, all I've seen take 19, 19.5 or 20V DC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: The power source must be capable of providing the rated voltage and current. The load (laptop computer in this case) will draw as much current as necessary under operating conditions. If the source resistance is too large then as the load draws more current its operating voltage drops. When the operating voltage is too low for proper operation of electronics this is called a brownout condition. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11252/reading-and-understanding-electrical-specs-on-laptop-ac-adapters and https://superuser.com/questions/113113/why-are-brownouts-so-harmful

Comment: Not AC sorry, DC. It is an old Sony Vaio and I found the wall adapter so problem solved but I want to know more. Thank you for the links, I need to do some reading

Answer (score 0):

Current is drawn, voltage is pushed. Normally a device that pulls 3 Amps at 19 volts will pull 3 Amps from any 19v supply.

But modern laptops require some sort of signaling device. The plugs typically have 3 or 4 conductors and either a resistor or active i2c or 1 wire or SPI device type eeprom that tells it what current it can pull.

Trying to use a random power supply that doesn't conform to the signaling standard as your laptop may either prompt a warning or it will prevent your laptop from charging.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamentals of electronics is Ohm's Law which says that for a given resistance, the current through the resistance is proportional to the voltage applied: `E [voltage] = I [current] * R [resistance]` or, by applying algebra, `I = E/I`. Thus, if you take a simple resistive device, such as an incandescent light bulb (actually, the resistance varies with temperature, but once to full temperature, it's basically a simple resistor), the current flowing through is directly proportional to the voltage applied. This is why you can simply plug a lamp into the wall and it will draw the right current for its wattage (assuming your mains voltage is correct).

Similarly, your laptop, with the correct voltage applied will draw it's required current. If the laptop needs 2 amps, it doesn't care if the power brick is rated for 2 amps or 200 amps. Now a computer is not a simple resistive device and the current drawn will vary with the amount of work it's doing, but the idea is still the same.

Now many laptops will have a third wire going from the brick and often this is used to identify the current capability of the power brick and the computer will attempt to not draw more current than the brick can supply (using the battery as a "buffer") or refuse to even work with an off-brand brick. However, this is not required to power a laptop from a power brick.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy a new power supply.

First of all it is unlikely that your laptop works with 19.5V AC, check again if it is DC, as you may have a fundamental problem already.

And generally a load would take correct amount of current when connected to correct voltage, but laptops are not simple loads so they don't.

Generally laptops need to communicate with the power supply over a data wire before the laptop knows how much current is available.

Answer (score 0):

For practicality, it's best to buy a new charger, especially if you value your laptop. If it's something done for fun or for educational purposes, not a bad idea if you have spare chargers or PSU.

> does there also have to be some kind of current limit inside the power
> supply device? Or is that just a bit of info regarding what the Laptop
> will normally use?

Overcurrent protection for the power supply itself is of course needed, but assuming the laptop isn't broken I wouldn't worry about the laptop drawing more current than the stock power supply is supposed to deliver. Replacing stock chargers with aftermarket chargers with higher current ratings has been done with older laptops quite a lot.

As @Justme has said, some DC laptop power supplies have a way of telling the laptop how much it's able to deliver. I'll share my experience with repairing laptop chargers, but keep in mind I could be wrong or they could have changed the protocol anytime.

- Lenovo and HP have usually had a third additional ID pin with a resistor connected to the voltage pin. With different resistance values for different charger wattage, the laptop knows how much current it can safely pull from the charger
- LG and Samsung laptops usually come with just DC 2-pin connectors without any way to let the laptop know of the wattage. They would usually stop drawing more current if it senses a voltage drop. I believe ASUS, Acer chargers also work this way but not very certain.
- Dell has one of the most sophisticated protocols, using a 1-wire protocol between the laptop and the charger. It's the safest way but kinda overengineered. I wouldn't try to repair Dell chargers unless I feel like wasting my time.